# Calculating yearly return from daily return data

Tags: r, aggregate, finance

I have imported daily return data for ADSK via a downloaded Yahoo finance .csv file.

```
ADSKcsv <- read.csv("ADSK.csv", TRUE)
```

I have converted the .csv file to a data frame

```
class(ADSKcsv)
```

I have selected the two relevant columns that I want to work with and sought to take the mean of all daily returns for each year. I do not know how to do this.

```
aggregate(Close~Date, ADSK, mean)
```

The above code yields a mean calculation for each date. My objective is to calculate YoY return from this data, first converting daily returns to yearly returns, then using yearly returns to calculate year-over-year returns. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest an easier approach?

```
library(tidyquant)

ADSK_yearly_returns_tbl <- tq_get("ADSK") %>%
  tq_transmute(select = close,
            mutate_fun = periodReturn,
            period = "yearly")

ADSK_yearly_returns_tbl
```

If you run the above code, it will download the historical returns for a symbol of interest (`ADSK` in this case) and then calculate the yearly return. An added bonus to using this workflow is that you can swap out any symbols of interest without manually downloading and reading them in. Plus, it saves you the extra step of calculating the average daily return.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the year value from `date` and then do `aggregate` :

This can be done in base R :

```
aggregate(Close~year, transform(ADSKcsv, year = format(Date, '%Y')), mean)
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
ADSKcsv %>%
  group_by(year = format(Date, '%Y')) %>%
  #Or using lubridate's year function
  #group_by(year = lubridate::year(Date)) %>%
  summarise(Close = mean(Close))
```

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ADSKcsv)[, .(Close = mean(Close)), format(Date, '%Y')]
```